# Microprofile Fault Tolerance Unit Test

Tags: java, quarkus, fault-tolerance, microprofile

I am using Qurkus with `Microprofile Fault Tolerance` to implement foult tollerance on a JDBC connection ([Dremio](https://docs.dremio.com/drivers/dremio-jdbc-driver.html)).

I have implemented something like that:

```java
class Repository {

 
   private final DataSource dataSource; //initialized on constructor
   
   
   Collection<String> getData() exception SQLException {
      try (var conn = dataSource.getConnection();
             var stmt = conn.createStatement();
             var rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
           var result = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (rs.next()) {
                 result.add(rs.getString("data"));
            }
          return result;
      } catch(SQLException e) {
          //log and throw custom exception
      }
   }
}

class Service {
   @Inject
   Repository repo;

   public Collection<String> callService() {
            //other code that dosen't require retries
            try {
               var res = getData();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                 //log exception
                 throw new CustomException(e);
            }
            return res;
   }

   @Retry()
   private Collection<String> getData() throw Exception {
       return repo.getData();
  }

}
```

Now I am trying to test the retry with Unit Test. I didn't find any documentation related to `Microprofile Fault Tolerance`.

```java
@QuarkusTest
class ServiceTest {

    @Inject
    Service service;

    @InjectMock
    Repository repository;

    @Test
    void shouldHandleRetryWhenErrorOccursDuringQueryData() throws Exception {

        ArrayList<String> expectedResult = Lists.newArrayList("1","2");

        when(repository.getData())
             .thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Runtime Exception"))
             .thenReturn(expectedResult);

        Collection<String> executionResult = service.callService();

        assertIterableEquals(expectedResult, executionResult);

    }
}
```

My expectation is that the data return after one retry (the first call to `getData` return an error). Instead return only the error.

Which is the corrrect way in order to testing the retries of my method?

Answer (score 0):

Mocks unfortunately can't be used with Fault Tolerance annotations because Mockito effectively overrides everything about the original method, including the `@Retry` annotation. You can fix this by moving the `@Retry` annotation onto something that you don't mock (the `Service.callService()` method), so that `callService` method will be retried instead, and on the second attempt, the call to the repository will go through.

Comment: your solution sounds good, but in the service function I have other code that should not re-executed on the retries.

Comment: Hmm, in that case I think you'll need one more intermediary wrapper around the repository, and the `@Retry` annotation will be applied on that..

Comment: But there's also the question whether this is a good idea at all, you're testing the retry functionality built in Quarkus rather than testing your own business code. This is something that is covered in the Quarkus test suites. So your test only makes sense if you really don't trust the Quarkus team that they test properly ;)

Comment: I verifying that my logic return errors or data even with retries. I don't test the retry logic.